# Cannot build Boost::Locale with ICU 53.1 on Visual C++ 2013

Tags: boost, boost-locale

I'm trying to build Boost::Locale (Boost version 1.56) using the 'Building Boost.Locale' instructions.  Firstly, I successfully installed the complete Boost library a few months ago, which created a number of Boost::Locale .dll & .lib files:

```
boost_locale-vc120-mt-1_56.dll
boost_locale-vc120-mt-1_56.lib
boost_locale-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.dll
boost_locale-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib
```

Today, I downloaded ICU4C 53.1 and built it (both debug and release).  I added the following directory to my computer path:

```
d:\icu\bin
```

Next, I ran the ICU tests and they ran fine.

Then I tried to link Boost::Locale with ICU and did the following as indicated in the Locale installation directions:

From the command prompt, I typed:

```
.\bjam -sICU_PATH=d:\icu --with-locale stage
```

It indicated that it was building and displayed '...patience...found 1214 targets...' on screen

Here are the results of D:\boost_1_56_0\bin.v2\config.log:

```
...found 1 target...
...updating 1 target...
config-cache.write bin.v2\project-cache.jam
...updated 1 target...
```

At this point, I don't know what 'target' got updated so I created a small test app using **get_all_backends()** to see what backends were being supported.  Unfortunately, only **winapi** and **std** were listed.

Can someone suggest what may have gone wrong?

**UPDATE**

Upon opening up the Locale jam file:

```
searched-lib icudt : :  <search>$(ICU_PATH)/lib
                        <name>icudata
                        <link>shared
                        <runtime-link>shared ;
```

I am not sure about this but the snippet above refers to icudt and I noticed that the dll files have the version of ICU appended, i.e.: **icudt**

I'm going to update the references to match the appended version, i.e.: **icudt53** and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I got Boost Locale working fine, but for some reason, I could never do it using the Boost Locale instructions.  If the Boost Locale installation instructions work for you, good.  If not, you can do what I did and do a complete rebuild of Boost.

The following assumes that you have correctly built ICU and included it into your path.

1. change directory to boost root, e.g.: d:\boost_1_56_0
2. type: bootstrap
3. bjam -sICU_PATH=d:\icu --toolset=msvc-12.0 --build-type=complete stage

The above worked just fine for me.  Just make sure to specify the version of VC++, in my case above 12.0

Comment: I'm also having some troubles building boost::locale 1.57.0 with ICU 54.1. After specifying the directory using with -sICU_PATH nd running bjam I get a message saying "Performing configuration checks...  icu                      : no, icu (lib64): no" It's like it does not detect the library... I will try to rebuild the whole library instead of just boost::locale to see if it makes any difference

Comment: @ChrisPeterson, specifying the sICU_PATH and building the entire library was the only way that it worked for me.  Make sure that you have ICU built beforehand.  I've done this a number of times on couple of PC's and it definitely works.